# Cantilever Beam Deflection with load in middle of beam

Tags: resonance, structural-beam

How can I calculate the deflection of a Cantilever beam if there is a load at different points on the beam? My current scenario is the following → I have a ruler that I have modelled to be cantilever and I am moving a piece of blu-tac down the ruler to calculate different resonance frequencies. Is there a formula relating the position of blu tac and deflection? Or any relationship between this and its centre of gravity

Comment: You have used the tag for resonance but your question is asking about deflection of the beam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theoretical method is

- Draw the shear force and bending moment diagram for the beam with the point load
- Calculate the curvature at any point from the bending moment
- Integrate the curvature twice to get the deflection

You should find this in any textbook on "strength of materials" with a section on beam bending.

The practical method is find a beam calculator program on the internet that does the calculations for you!

Comment: Is there a given formula I can work out using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Based on structx.com formula here:

https://structx.com/Beam_Formulas_017.html

This is the formula:

[image: Fixed Both Ends Beam - Point Load at Any Point]

There is fomula for other types (like cantilever etc as well):

https://structx.com/beams.html